# Github CI error because google.services.json and local.properties not found

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, github, github-actions

I have a `yml` as this :

```
name: Android CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11

      # Runs ktlint
      - name: Lint
        run: ./gradlew ktlintCheck

      # Execute unit tests
      - name: Unit Test
        run: ./gradlew testDebugUnitTest
```

And now I'm adding the SignInWithFirebase and I need to add two things :

```
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  /home/runner/work/MyApp/MyApp/app/src/debug/google-services.json
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
  /home/runner/work/MyApp/MyApp/app/src/google-services.json
  /home/runner/work/MyApp/MyApp/app/src/Debug/google-services.json
  /home/runner/work/MyApp/MyApp/app/google-services.json
```

And also the problem is if I add the key that gives me firebase I've used the `local.properties` and since I have this in the `.gitignore` it fails with :

> The file '/home/runner/work/MyApp/MyApp/local.properties' could not be found

Any idea how can I handle this?

Comment: Have you pushed `google-services.json` and `local.properties`? If not, try removing them from `.gitignore`

Comment: I've not pushed it because they are private..

Comment: That is the reason why your project won't build!

Comment: Note that both the `checkout` and the `setup-java` action have a newer version `v3`

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, the reason for the project to not build is because `google-services.json` and `local.properties` are not pushed.

As an alternative to pushing the original `google-services.json`, you can create a mirror project with the same content on Firebase & override `google-services.json` on debug flavour. This should be sufficient for the project to build.

Also, I think `google-services.json` is causing the problem & not `local.properties`. So, please try the above solution.